# Installing Octopress on Mountain Lion: rehash issue

Tags: ruby, macos, octopress

I was trying to get my Ruby 1.9.3 running for my Octopress installation.

When I  typed:

```
rbenv rehash
```

I got an error:

```
rbenv: cannot rehash: /Users/my-computer-name/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim exists
```

How to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following commands:

```
rm -rf /Users/my-computer-name/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim
rbenv rehash
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo rbenv rehash`

Mine just needed the `sudo`